# Boots to a black screen when a Microsoft Wirless Mobile Mouse 3500 is plugged in

Tags: 11.04, boot-failure

If I boot Ubuntu 11.04 and I have a Microsoft Wirless Mobile Mouse 3500 plugged in, nothing happens after I reach the grub screen and select Ubuntu for booting (I get the grub screen at boot since I'm dual booting).

The screen just stays purple for a few seconds then goes black. I can access a terminal session and log in there. If I try to get back to the GUI by hitting ctrl alt f7 I get some text about my graphics card I believe (this is standard white on black text, and I don't know how to get it off the screen without transcribing it).

So far I can confirm the problem arises consistently when the mouse was on during the previous session (last time the computer was booted), but turned off before the faulty boot.

Here is some of the text I see when the error occurs which might be relevant:

```
[   15.887693] Process modprobe (pid: 519, threadinfo ffff88014529e000, task ffff8801452c2dc0)
```

Then there is a call trace, so I guess something screwed up pretty good and the resulting lines include a lot of [radeon], radeon_device, radeon_pci, radeon_driver, radeon_init ... which leads me to believe the error was caused by my video card, although it is certainly catalyzed by the mouse.

Is anything known about this? Should I make a bug report and if so how? The bug report tool referred me to here as I had no idea what package to report.

Comment: Can you add the errors from the trace? Might help finding an answer.

Comment: So does your computer boot correctly when you unplug the mouse?